# iTunes Connect - set last iOS compatible

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, incompatibility

On App store, I have a old app that are not ok with iOS 9.
I don't want to recompile it.

Is there a way to set the "last version compatibl" on iTunes connect? (so iOS 8 and less user can still continue to use it.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do that. Reasons? I believe is the way to required an upgrade your app to the newest technology. It's not fair but its does not have other option.